# mysql very low speed when looping through table after inserting a hug number of rows

Tags: mysql

I have a procedure in MYSQL database that should collect some data from multiple tables and loop through it.

I have created a table to insert this data in it, the table has a primary key and a none unique index.

The inserted data is about 200000 rows, the insert is don in few seconds, but the while loop takes very long time (about 30 mins) to complete!!!

The while loop code is something like below:

```
    SET @I = 0;
    WhileLoop: WHILE (1=1)
       SELECT KeyRW
       INTO @I
       FROM MyTable
       WHERE KeyRW> @I
       ORDER BY KeyRW
       LIMIT 1;

       IF @I IS NULL THEN
           leave WhileLoop;
       END IF;

      (Some simple calculation...)

    END WHILE WhileLoop;
```

We moved the loop code into another procedure and execute it manually after the insert is done (there was a few minutes delay) and it executed very very faster!!!

Then we moved the loop back into the previous procedure and added a delay before it, and now its working, it seems that MYSQL is indexing data asyncly and we should wait for it!!

Did i understand correctly?

If yes then how much should we wait based on size of data?

If no then whats the problem and why a delay is solving this?

Comment: Do you really need a loop inside the procedure? The code sample does not show the actual logic. Serializing the SQL queries (using loops) is usually the thing you try to avoid.

Comment: Yes its necessary, and its very easier with a loop, because each row is depended on 1st or 2st or ... prev or next rows